# Why has nautilus' "Send to..." context menu replaced with "Email..."

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

I have been using Ubuntu for quite sometime and I've always seen the context menu "**Send to...**" where a dialog pops up showing all the places I could send my file to. But, after upgrading to 14.04, I noticed that the context menu had changed and it now has "**Email...**" in its place.

I don't use that menu much but it is annoying and confusing. If I were to send a file to a contact from empathy, I wouldn't be "emailing" it, I would just be "sending" it.

*Ubuntu 14.04 Linux AAPC-2 3.13.0-30-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 9 22:45:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

Comment: Maybe you can report it to nautilus bugtracker on [Launchpad](http://launchpad.com). Good sighting!

Comment: I have, actually. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1332731

Comment: Just right click and select "email" a pop-up will come up where you could choose from drop down. Its working for me on 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: Same as anujsharma9196, I have 14.04, and upon selecting Email option, a popup appears where I can select Empathy, Email, CD/DVD, Bluetooth, and Shared Drives. Although technically this works, but "Email" option in and of itself is misleading